# Python regex to get returned value from a string

Tags: python, regex

Perl has some good and easy function to set the returned value to a variable

```
if($string =~ /<(\w+)>/){
     $name = $1;
}
```

This is what I tried for python and it works, but is there any alternative way of doing this?

```
if re.match('\s*<\w+>.+', string):
    var = re.findall('>(\w+)<', string)
```

Comment: You should add `.group(0)` to the end of the `var` line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this is what you looking for:

```
string = "id: 10"
match = re.search("id: (\d+)", string)
if match:
    id = match.group(1)
    print id
```

Whatever you need, you have possibly everything in [Python re doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the `match` followed by `findall`, `findall` will return an empty list when there's no match:

```
>>> string = 'sdafasdf asdfas '
>>> var = re.findall('>(\w+)<', string)
>>> var
[]
```

So, you can translate your `Perl` example like this:

```
try: name = re.findall('>(\w+)<', string)[0]
except IndexError: name = 'unknown'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you regex will match anything. They both contradict each other.

This is how you would do a match in Python:

```
import re

string = "string"
matches = re.match('(\w+)', string)
print matches.group()
```